# How to implement JAVA program in ANDROID?

Tags: android

I am creating an android application which is my final year project.I am actually electrical engineer.But i have knowledge in writing programs.In electrical there was a problem(sum) named ADMITTANCE BUS MATRIX.For this problem I have finished JAVA PROGRAM completely.I know that it is not possible to implement the same JAVA PROGRAM in ANDROID.Then how can I implement my program in ANDROID.
Please help me!!.I have only 2 days to finish this...Below is my code which also uses user defined library named "Flanagan"...If anybody cant understand my question please reply here!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import flanagan.complex.Complex;
import flanagan.io.PrintToScreen;
import flanagan.math.*;
import flanagan.complex.ComplexMatrix;

public class Admittance 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int r,c=4,x=1;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers of linedata:::");
    r=in.nextInt();
    double[][] ydata=new double[r][c];
    System.out.println("Enter LineData:::");
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
            ydata[i][j]=in.nextDouble();

    //Storing From bus and To bus
    double[][] fb=new double[r][x];
    double[][] tb=new double[r][x];
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
        {
            fb[i][j]=ydata[i][j];
            tb[i][j]=ydata[i][j+1];
        }
    }   
    double m[]=new double[1];
    Matrix ff=new Matrix(fb);
    m=ff.maximumElement();
    System.out.println("The maxima of from bus is:::");
    System.out.println(+m[0]);


    double m1[]=new double[3];
    Matrix tt=new Matrix(tb);
    m1=tt.maximumElement();
    System.out.println("The maxima of to bus is:::");
    System.out.println(+m1[0]);

    int ft;
    int mb;
    ft=(int)m[0];
    int dt;
    dt=(int)m1[0];
    if(ft>dt)
        mb=ft;
    else
        mb=dt;
    System.out.println("The maxmum no. of bus is:::");
    System.out.print(+mb);
    Complex[][] aa = Complex.twoDarray(r,x);
    Complex[][] ab = Complex.twoDarray(r,x);
    Complex[][] zbus = Complex.twoDarray(r,x);
    //Impedance
    for ( int e = 0 ; e < r ; e++ )
      {
          for ( int d = 0 ; d < x ; d++ )
          {
             aa[e][d] = new Complex(ydata[e][2], ydata[e][3]);
          }
      }
      System.out.println();
      PrintToScreen.print(aa);
      //Admittance
      for ( int e = 0 ; e < r ; e++ )
      {
          for ( int d = 0 ; d < x ; d++ )
          {
             ab[e][d] = aa[e][d].inverse();
          }
      }

      PrintToScreen.print(ab);
      Complex[][] ybus = Complex.twoDarray(mb,mb);
      PrintToScreen.print(ybus);
    int[][] ffb=new int[r][x];
    int[][] ttb=new int[r][x];
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
        {
            ffb[i][j]=(int)fb[i][j];
            ttb[i][j]=(int)tb[i][j];
        }
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    { 
        for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(+ffb[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(+ttb[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

      //Off Diagonal
      for(int k=0;k<r;k++)
          if(ffb[k][0]>0&&ttb[k][0]>0)
          {
              ybus[ffb[k][0]-1][ttb[k][0]-1]=Complex.plus(ybus[ffb[k][0]-1][ttb[k] [0]-1],ab[k][0].negate());
              ybus[ttb[k][0]-1][ffb[k][0]-1]=ybus[ffb[k][0]-1][ttb[k][0]-1];
          }
      //Main diagonal
      for(int i=0;i<mb;i++)
          for(int k=0;k<r;k++)
              if(((ffb[k][0]-1)==i)||((ttb[k][0]-1)==i))
                  ybus[i][i]=Complex.plus(ybus[i][i],ab[k][0]);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("The Admittance Bus of given data is : \n");
      PrintToScreen.print(ybus);
      ComplexMatrix yb = new ComplexMatrix(ybus);
      ComplexMatrix zb = new ComplexMatrix(mb,mb);
      zb=yb.inverse();
      zbus=zb.getArrayCopy();
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("The Impedance Bus of given data is : \n ");
      PrintToScreen.print(zbus);
    in.close();
}
}
```

Comment: This is your final project? And you get two days to complete it? *confused*

Comment: Sir i am final year electrical engineer student and my project is to create an android application.I am having only 2 days to complete this..Already i have done java program for my project..I cant implement this in ANDROID..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try http://jbed.en.malavida.com/android/.

Its an app that runs java apps on an android.

Comment: A utility that runs Java programs on an operating system built to run Java programs... I'm not sure how I feel about this.

Comment: Yeah I don't like it either, your suggestion is what should have been done from the start.

Answer (score 2):

Given that most Android apps are written in Java, you don't actually have to do much work. For the most part, you just have to download and install the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (if you use Linux, there's even a plugin), and then create an `Activity`.

Moreover, you can look at [Android's tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=cn) page for a basic application, and essentially create an `EditText` field, as well as a `TextView` to display the result. You can find all of this stuff, in more detail, at the aforementioned [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=cn).

Comment: I have ANDROID SDK tool and everything needed to create an android app.But i dont know how to make the program to print on mobile's screen.System.out.println() doesnt work in mobile or emulator,right??
Then how can i print the result to mobiles screen...

Comment: @user3296855 You're going to have to make a TextView, and then set the view's text to the result. You can probably find some sample code online.

Comment: Can i print the matrix??

Comment: Sir,pls help me!!Can i print the matrix in mobile's screen and can i use user defined library in creating android application